# How to pass an initializer list as a function argument?

Tags: c++

Basically, I'm looking to do something like this:

```
HANDLE hThread1 = CreateThread(...);
HANDLE hThread2 = CreateThread(...);
HANDLE hThread3 = CreateThread(...);

...

WaitForMultipleObjects( 3, {hThread1,hThread2,hThread3}, FALSE, INFINITE );
```

instead of this:

```
HANDLE hThread[3];
hThread[0] = CreateThread(...);
hThread[1] = CreateThread(...);
hThread[2] = CreateThread(...);

...

WaitForMultipleObjects( 3, hThread, FALSE, INFINITE );
```

The only solution I've found is using `std::initializer_list`, but obviously `WaitForMultipleObjects()` doesn't doesn't accept an `std::initializer_list`

Comment: Rewrite `WaitForMultipleObjects` then. While you're at it, it might be an alternative to use a variadically templated function instead.

Comment: @KerrekSB: `WaitForMultipleObjects` is a WinAPI call.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Ah, that explains it. A wrapper comes to mind then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write a wrapper, then.

```
DWORD wait_for_multiple_objects(
    std::initializer_list<HANDLE> handles,
    bool wait_all = false, DWORD time = INFINITE
) {
    return WaitForMultipleObjects(
        handles.size(), &*handles.begin(), wait_all, time
    );
}
```

Now you can do:

```
wait_for_multiple_objects({ handle1, handle2, handle3 });
```

This obviously requires C++11 compiler that supports `initializer_list`. `std::vector<HANDLE>` might be a better type for the argument if you expect to pass an already-existing one. Or a more generic iterator/range interface, but that's left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus- Out of curiosity, why not just take an `initializer_list` as an argument directly?  Is there a reason not to do this, or is this just personal preference?

Comment: @templatetypedef: Hell if I remember. That const ref is crappy anyway, so I'll edit.