# How to pass brace enclosed initializer list as an argument?

Tags: c, function

*This is a copy of the this post: [Brace Enclosed Initializer List As Function Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004102/brace-enclosed-initializer-list-as-function-argument), though I am looking for a solution using only methods available in C. I am using the Windows 8 compiler.*

Basically, I'm looking to do something like this:

```
HANDLE hThread1 = CreateThread(...);
HANDLE hThread2 = CreateThread(...);
HANDLE hThread3 = CreateThread(...);

...

WaitForMultipleObjects( 3, {hThread1,hThread2,hThread3}, FALSE, INFINITE );
```

instead of this:

```
HANDLE hThread[3];
hThread[0] = CreateThread(...);
hThread[1] = CreateThread(...);
hThread[2] = CreateThread(...);

...

WaitForMultipleObjects( 3, hThread, FALSE, INFINITE );



foo(arg1, arg2, {arg3_1, arg3_2});
```

Comment: I misunderstand your question.  You want to use `std::foo`, which is C++, in C?

Comment: It was a copy of the original question. I simply want to use parameters like so: `arbitraryFunction(arg1, args, {arg3_1, arg3_2});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C99 provides compound literals, which *would* give you what you want:

```
WaitForMultipleObjects( 3,
                        (HANDLE*){hThread1, hThread2, hThread3},
                        FALSE,
                        INFINITE );
```

Unfortunately, Microsoft has said that they have no interest in supporting any C standard past C90, except for those features that happen to be part of C++ (and C++ doesn't have compound literals).

You could write a variadic function that builds an array of `HANDLE`s and returns a pointer to its first element.  A call then might look like:

```
WaitForMultipleObjects( 3,
                        HandleList(3, hThread1, hThread2, hThread3),
                        FALSE,
                        INFINITE );
```

But then you have the usual problems of managing the memory allocated for the array.

C90 doesn't provide a particularly clean way of doing what you want.

Comment: There's a limit (32? 64?) to how many handles the wait function can take, so he could allocate the max on the stack and not worry about memory management. (Might be slightly slow in a loop but whatever.)