# Combining prefix &* operations in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

In the answer to [How to pass an initializer list as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004102/how-to-pass-an-initializer-list-as-a-function-argument), I see the expression:

```
return WaitForMultipleObjects(
    handles.size(), &*handles.begin(), wait_all, time
);
```

What's the point of the `&*`? Would the call have the same meaning without it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- In general, `container.begin()` returns an iterator
- In general, `&*container.begin()` returns a pointer
- `WaitForMultipleObjects` expects a `HANDLE const*`

For `std::initializer_list<>` in particular, the iterator is defined *to be* a pointer; but A) this is not generalizable to other container types, and B) standard library implementations often use checked iterators in debug builds, which are necessarily UDTs.

For the particular answer you linked to, the `&*` is *not* necessary because it is specifically using `std::initializer_list<>`; however, if `wait_for_multiple_objects` instead took a `std::array<>` or `std::vector<>`, or if it were made into a function template that could take any random-access container, it would indeed be necessary.